# Commutator-realisable connected simply connected Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups

Suppose that, for a connected simply connected real Lie group G, there is a Lie group H such that
G = H′ (the commutator subgroup of H). Can H always be chosen to be connected; that is, is there a connected Lie group K such that G = K'?

Such an H is often called an integral for G in general group theory, but that terminology is, perhaps, misleading in the case of Lie groups.

My motivation for the question is that I am trying to answer the following question that was raised in a paper: "Is it true that a Lie algebra is integrable if and only
if the corresponding Lie group is?" I believe that I have a proof if the question I have asked has a positive answer.

Comment: Do you have an example of a connected Lie group not equal to the commutator subgroup of another Lie group (possibly disconnected)?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I wondered if you took one of the connected components of H (of the identity element?) or the simply connected cover, whether they would have the same commutator subgroup.

Comment: Here's my latest attempt at an answer.

Claim: Let $H_0$ be the connected component of the identity of $H$. Then $G=H_0'$. The Lie algebra of H is also the Lie algebra of $H_0$. Now, by (1), the Lie algebra of $H_0'$ is ${\mathfrak h}'$, which is also the Lie algebra of G. I now want to say that $G=H_0'$, but this seems to require that $H_0'$ is simply connected.  


(1) L. Greenberg, `Commutator groups and algebras'. Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards B. Mathematical Sciences 73B (3), (1969), 247-249:
https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn3p247 A1b.pdf

Comment: I should say that work on nonassociative algebras and my Lie group theory is rather rusty.

Comment: No, your proof fails in the very first step. Think about $H$ which is the isometry group of the real line and $G$ which is the additive group of real numbers. But you get this $G$ as the derived subgroup of the Heisenberg group.

Comment: OK, thanks Moishe.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how your example relates to my 'proof', Moishe. Are you saying that the claim is wrong, rather than the first line of the proof (which is about the Lie algebra of  $H$). So, are you saying that $H_0$ is the Heisenberg group?

Comment: I'm not saying that $H_0$ is the Lie group $K$ such that $G=K'$. To finish off the 'proof', can we say that $H_0'$ is connected and so $G=H_0'$ since both are associated with the Lie algebra $[{\mathfrak h}, {\mathfrak h}]$ and both are connected.?

Comment: The first sentence above should read "I'm not saying that $H_0$ is the only Lie group $K$ such that $G=K′$."

Comment: I am saying that your proof is wrong. I am also saying that there is a totally unrelated connected Lie group $N$ such that ${\mathbb R}= N'$, namely, $N$ is the Heisenberg group.